# node.js: Is it possible to pass jQuery code in server-side html response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        displayForm(res);
    } else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        //processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res);
        processFormFieldsIndividual(req, res);
    }
});

function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

I am following [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-and-handling-forms-in-node-js/) example, where form.html contains only html blocks.
 My question is, can't jQuery/javaScript code be merged with form.html in server response? 
I have tried both external and internal js code but to no avail.

Comment: "can't jQuery/javaScript code be merged with form.html in server response?" — Define "merged".

Comment: "I have tried both external and internal js code but to no avail." — Tried how? We can't tell why code you haven't shared with us isn't working. http://sscce.org/

Comment: short answer: `no`. long answer: you can use a variety of tools like jsdom or cheerio to accomplish that on a specific basis with lots of customization and debugging. that said, the complications of using those methodologies usually negates any benefit of code re-use, unless you're really going "all in" to hybrid rendering, in which case you probably would be asking a different question...

Comment: @dandavis — I would have said, "Yes, of course", but I had a completely different interpretation of this vaguely worded question. :)

Comment: @Quentin html form with javascript code written within <script></script> blocks. The html form when opened directly runs the javascript code. But doesn't when returned as a response from the node.js server.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the input. I would have guessed the same short answer.

Comment: @SaadH — The choice of server won't make any difference there. Some other factor must be involved. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Quentin, I checked the console of browser, and it is giving me `Unexpected token <` errors for the first line of my jQuery and external js file. Both files don't have `<` in the first line. When I checked the source files in browser, both jQuery and external.js files were not loaded, and they were showing the code of form.html with first line `<html>` being underlined in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser asks for the JavaScript file, it makes a GET request to your server.

Your server checks the request and, if it is a GET request, returns the content of `form.html`.

You need to check the request object to see what path is being requested and serve the content the browser is asking for instead of always serving the content of `form.html`.

Comment: Thanks, this could possibly be the reason. [Documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)
Any idea which method could be used to determine that?

Comment: How about message.url?

Comment: ok, I guess we are close to the solution. 
    `if (req.url == '/js/jquery.js' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get')
    {
        //what should be done here?
    }`

Comment: You remember how you read the content of a static HTML file and gave it an apropriate content-type? The same thing.

Comment: I have added this code in the createServer function:
`else if ((req.url == '/js/jquery.js' || req.url == '/js/external.js') && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'){
  res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Length': 100
        });
        res.write('This is javascript file');
        res.end();
 }`
Nothing happens. Even explicitly typing the address: localhost/js/jquery.js doesn't do anything.

Comment: `else if`? So you only check to see if jQuery is being requests if it is not a GET request?

Comment: The content type for a JavaScript program is `application/javascript` not `text/plain` … and don't specify a content length of 100 bytes unless your content actually is 100 bytes long.

Comment: great! it worked. For some reason, the server was unable to find js file in subdirectory `fs.readFile('/js/jquery.js')`, so when I placed the file in the same folder it worked fine :)

Comment: regarding `else if`, the check (`else if`) for js get request is before `else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get')`